# Oracle SQL ORA-00600: Error with GREATEST and regexp_replace sub query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a small piece of code which has a sub query using the `regexp_replace` function to get a time stamp and this is inside a `GREATEST` function to get the highest date from this and a field in the outer query.

The data I am using in the sub query looks like this:

```
IDDate      IDKeys
17-DEC-16   Q=INT^A_NO=123^
03-OCT-18   B_ID=123^
18-OCT-18   C_ID=123^
28-OCT-18   C_ID=123^
```

If I run this segment of code:

```
SELECT MAX(IDDate) GDATE
FROM HHL h
WHERE regexp_replace(IDKeys, '[^0-9]', '') = '123'
AND LEFT(IDKeys, 1) = 'C'
```

It returns the correct information

```
GDATE
28-OCT-18
```

However when I incorporate this into the outer query as a sub query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
c.P_ID,
GREATEST((SELECT MAX(IDDate) GDATE
          FROM HHL h
          WHERE regexp_replace(IDKeys, '[^0-9]', '') = c.P_ID
          AND LEFT(IDKeys, 1) = 'C'), c.CIDDate) GCDate
FROM CICC c
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkqcsfixfro:1 -- frooutj], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
*Cause: This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program
        exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered a low-level,
        unexpected condition. The first argument is the internal message
        number. This argument and the database version number are critical in
        identifying the root cause and the potential impact to your system.
```

> EDIT

This works if I use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions rather than `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
c.P_ID,
GREATEST((SELECT MAX(IDDate) GDATE
          FROM HHL h
          WHERE SUBSTR(NVL(SUBSTR(IDKeys, 0, INSTR(IDKeys, '^')-1), IDKeys), INSTR(NVL(SUBSTR(IDKeys, 0, INSTR(IDKeys, '^')-1), IDKeys), '=') + 1) = c.P_ID
          AND LEFT(IDKeys, 1) = 'C'), c.CIDDate) GCDate
FROM CICC c
```

Comment: Well, you probably found a bug in Oracle :-)

Comment: @Matt . . . I'm confused.  Given your initial data, 18-Oct and 28-Oct should both be returned.  Are you sure there is not another error causing this problem?  Nevertheless, you should not be getting internal Oracle errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `28-OCT-18` would be returned as I want MAX(IDDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you should create a service request to Oracle support. Seems like you face the **Bug 19894622 - ORA-600 [kkqcsfixfro:1 -- frooutj] error occur in 12c (Doc ID 19894622.8)**. Affected software versions are Versions >= 12.1.0.1 but BELOW 12.2. You should at least verify with your dba what software version you have and if patching will solve the problem.

There is a walk around described in the note.

```
alter session set "_optimizer_unnest_scalar_sq"=false;
```

As you can see it refers to the hidden parameter which is set on the session level. If you want to set this parameter on instance level the best practice with such parameters is to confirm with Oracle Support that setting this parameter is recommended by them.

Comment: ORA-600 - go straight to Support.